# Wordpress composer issues

Tags: installation, composer

I'm using composer to install wordpress but I have a situation when I run composer install I end up with a nested wp-content directory as follows. (Wordpress is the root install directory)

- wordpress/wp-content/wp-content

All the default core Wordpress themes and plugins end up in the following directories.

- wordpress/wp-content/wp-content/themes
- wordpress/wp-content/wp-content/plugins

All my plugins in the composer file end up in the correct directories

- wordpress/wp-content/plugins
- wordpress/wp-content/themes

```
{
  "require": {
    "johnpbloch/wordpress": ">=5.4",
    "wpackagist-plugin/admin-menu-editor": "1.9.8",
    "wpackagist-plugin/autoptimize": "2.8.1",
    "wp-api/basic-auth": "dev-master",
    "wpackagist-plugin/blog2social": "6.6.0",
    "wpackagist-plugin/bulk-delete": "6.0.1",
    "wpackagist-plugin/contact-form-7": "5.3.2",
    "wpackagist-plugin/custom-post-type-permalinks": "3.4.4",
    "wpackagist-plugin/custom-post-type-ui": "1.8.2",
    "wp-cli/wp-cli-bundle": "*",
    "wpackagist-plugin/redis-cache": "^2.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "wordpress/wp-content/plugins/{$name}/": [
        "type:wordpress-plugin"
      ],
      "wordpress/wp-content/themes/{$name}/": [
        "type:wordpress-theme"
      ]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "wordpress"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the johnpbloch/wordpress package has the paths correct? (Or it's johnpbloch/wordpress-core now.) I'd guess it's a bug in that.

Comment: You can't have nested composer packages, the moment WordPress updates, composer will delete the wordpress folder and recreate it using the new version, destroying all the plugins themes and any user uploaded data in the process. You have to use a subdirectory install with separate `wordpress` and `wp-content` folders, you can't have a root folder install

Comment: @TomJNowell I mount the uploads directory afterwards so that's not a problem.

Comment: @Rup I'll double check I have the correct johnpbloch requires setup.

Comment: You can still end up in a situation where plugins and theme packages are missing due to the order packages were installed and updated. E.g. if WP is updated but the plugins aren't, then your plugins will be missing. Likewise, if a plugin is updated then WP is updated, the plugin will be missing. ***Never*** nest composer packages.

Comment: Instead you should either add an `index.php` that loads WP, or, configure `wp-config.php` so that the wp content URLs and paths etc are all correct, then tell Apache/Nginx to server `wp-content` at `/wp-content` and server `/` from `/wordpress`. There are other ways to do it but the root dir where the `wp-content` folder is inside the WP install is not the correct method. The `composer.json` in the question is wrong.

Comment: Can you try to set `wordpress-install-dir` to another subdir and not your root install? I agree with Tom, you'll end up having composer overwriting your files if they are saved in a subfolder of another package.